# Flutter size of projects created are too big

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am following a lot of tutorials to create flutter apps, however, I had created a simple hello world app in flutter, and just after compiling and running the IOS simulator, the folder size increased more than 300MB , I am using VS, is this normal? my folder of only 4 simple projects get more than 2.0GB, and those only have simple code, no relevant data, no assest

Answer (score 0):

**This brought my folder size from 15GB to 6.5GB after running this**

find . -name "pubspec.yaml" -execdir flutter clean

**decrease flutter  application size.**

https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/app-size

Answer (score 0):

when you are building a flutter app, a folder named build is created inside the root part the application, you can delete this folder as it is auto generated. also, if you are using git, .git file could get big in size.